# Can't boot in my Lubuntu 18 system. /dev/sda1: clean stuck for ever

Tags: boot, partitioning, lubuntu

I have a computer that wont boot. I had this problem some days ago and managed to resolve it temporarily by installing another Lubuntu version (18 too, but 64 bits). My original system worked fine for some days but now I am at the same place as before, except the newer Lubuntu boots Up fine. I already did a fsck of the partition where my original Lubuntu is (thanks to the newer Lubuntu recovery Mode, because I am unable to access to old Lubuntu recovery Mode)

What could be the problem? All solutions I have read requires me to boot Up on recovery Mode from the original system and I cant do that. What can I do?

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Comment: Lubuntu doesn't have *year* format releases (they are specialist *snap* only products from Ubuntu), Lubuntu being a desktop product provides *year.month* products that are *deb* package based, but can also used *snap* packages (18 != 18.04). The oldest *fully supported* release of Lubuntu is Lubuntu 20.04 LTS though - https://lubuntu.me/lubuntu-21-10-end-of-life-and-current-support-statuses/

Comment: If it was me, I'd boot the system into *runlevel 1*, ie. edit the kernel line & tell it to stop there.  I'd expect boot to succeed but even if it doesn't is ~equivalent to recovery mode, and if even it fails you'll see more messages that may provide details. Your details are incorrect & you're asking about an *unsupported* system or something that maybe *fake*, but that's what I'd do if my old IBM *i386* thinkpad failed to boot my 18.04 system.  If it doesn't provide clues; I'd boot *live* & check hardware for issues (SMART etc) given any *i386* machine has to be very old now.

Comment: The message you say is *stuck* is printed & completed; & relates to the prior boot more than the current one; ie. it's usually an indication of a system that had power-button held down to turn off last time instead of a *clean* shutdown via command (even SysRq key command direct to kernel)... ie. indication of bad-user behavior be it forced or not; far more than any system problem.  If you're not directing your system to shutdown/reboot via SysRq & using power to achieve it - that's why it's appearing.  Runlevel 1 will allow you to see other messages not currently showing.